# console.log not appearing on screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I feel that this is a very, very basic question, so please excuse me in advance. I've created both an HTML file that links to a Javascript file, and in the javascript file, I have console.log("Random Statement"). But it's blank for every browser I try it on.

I have tried reading forums, and have gathered something about "developer tools" and F12, and Firebug. But can someone please give me a concrete answer as to what I need to do to make "Random Statement" appear on the screen?

Comment: In Chrome/IE (Windows): F12, click "Console" tab, and you should see your message. The console usually logs to a separate window (e.g. "Developer Tools").

Comment: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners

Comment: Maybe you were looking for `document.write`(even if **I don't recommend it**)?

Comment: Are you looking for outputting info to the console (developer tools), or to the document?

Comment: well, it does appear on my screen just fine :P

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug, choose 'Console' from the menu at the top (it's the leftmost choice). When your call executes, the message will appear in the console window. I use console.debug rather than console.log.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use development tool (F12 for most browsers) or download Firefox and Firebug plugin(F12).

Console is a way of debuging your code (in case of errors).

You can also use alert(); or write() in Javascript

Also if you post some of your code, it would be useful for us to check your syntax, because that could also be an issue

Answer (score 0):

console.log writes to the browser's console. In chrome f12 pulls up the dev tools. From there click console to see the actual console.

alert() will output it in a dialog to the "screen"

$('#someId").html() will do it in jQuery to a particular DOM element id="someId"

Comment: And `document.getElementById('someId').innerHTML = ...;` does the same without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

How to use the Chrome console:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Answer (score -1):

Try this if you want `console.log` to output to the screen

```
console.log = function() {
    document.writeln(arguments[0]);
}
```

And then

```
console.log("Message");
```

Should do it